# Connection Error from Java Google Cloud Function to Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL)

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

Trying to connect to a Cloud SQL instance, I get the following error:

```
I        euw3-gsc-event-processor  keimftf9xzqf  2021-03-10 16:48:36.846  Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [gsc-shared-dev:europe-west3:euw3-db-gsc-shared-dev-1-gcp] via SSL socket.
I        euw3-gsc-event-processor  keimftf9xzqf  2021-03-10 16:48:36.847  First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
WARNING  euw3-gsc-event-processor  keimftf9xzqf  2021-03-10 16:48:36.848  Failed to execute org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher
                                                                          java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport.isMtls()'
                                                                                at com.google.api.services.sqladmin.SQLAdmin$Builder.chooseEndpoint(SQLAdmin.java:7296)
                                                                                at com.google.api.services.sqladmin.SQLAdmin$Builder.<init>(SQLAdmin.java:7329)
                                                                                at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.createAdminApiClient(CoreSocketFactory.java:322)
                                                                                at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.getInstance(CoreSocketFactory.java:130)
                                                                                at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.connect(CoreSocketFactory.java:229)
                                                                                at com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:76)
                                                                                at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:223)
```

This library is not directly in the cloud function jar. My pom.xml:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${google.cloud.libraries.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud.function}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-gcp</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud.function}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <!-- Required for Function primitives -->
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
            <version>${google.cloud.functions.api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions.invoker</groupId> 
            <artifactId>java-function-invoker</artifactId> <version>${google.cloud.functions.invoker.version}</version> 
            <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!-- Excluded JUnit 4 -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
                
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you have encountered a diamond dependency conflict. Two (or more) of your dependencies are pulling in the same dependency at a different version.

I'd suggest using `mvn dependency:tree` and see if you can figure out which dependency is repeated (probably a `google-api-client`).